# There is an automorphism of $\mathbb Z_6$ which is not an inner automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to show that there is an automorphism of $\mathbb Z_6$ which is not an inner automorphism. Since the generators of $\mathbb Z_6$ are 1 and 5, then we have two choices, we exclude the identity, it left only one possibility which it shouldn't be an inner automorphism, but my problem is I don't know how to prove that this automorphism isn't an inner automorphism.

I need help

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hint: the group is abelian, so it has no non-trivial inner automorphisms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this group is abelian (i.e. commutative), the inner automorphisms are all trivial.  So you only need to find a nontrivial automorphism.  Again, since this group is abelian, the inversion map is an automorphism (which is nontrivial in this case).

Comment: what is meant with the inversion map?

Comment: The map $g \mapsto g^{-1}$, taking an element to its inverse.

Answer (score 6):

If $G$ is abelian, then $a^{-1}xa = x$ for all $a, x \in G$, so the only inner automorphism is the identity. Thus it suffices to prove that an automorphism is not the identity.